# Why am I getting this error on Eclipse Openocd (arm7)?

Tags: c++, eclipse, arm, lpc

I have a project for LPC2387 and when I include `<iostream>` in main I'm getting this error on Eclipse: `address 0x40010500 of My_Project.elf section .stack is not within region RAM`.

Comment: Probably because (assuming you meant LPC2387) your RAM starts at 0x40000000 and ends at 0x4000FFFF.

Comment: yes, LPC, sorry. How can I fix it?